# Facebook API code

Tags: facebook

can someone show me PHP code for 
1) updating user status
2) display friends pics
3) display friends last status

script to should ask for authorization only once, must save the session and how to make it automatically connect when they got back later?

Comment: How's this? http://fbcookbook.ofhas.in/2009/02/07/facebook-reveals-status-api-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Thanks scott, but it doesnt explains how a script to should ask for authorization only once, must save the session and how to make it automatically connect when they got back later?

Answer (score 1):

Read this tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/
it may be help your to update status message and get facebook user infomation.
You can show friend picture with below fbml tag

```
<fb:profile-pic uid="[friend facebook id]" size="square" facebook-logo="true"></fb:profile-pic>
```

Best luck